# Asking user for array size and creating array of type Student

Tags: java, arrays, input, size

I have a Student class which has

```
 private String name;
 private long idNumber;
```

and getter and setters for them.

I then have a StudentTest class which I want to ask the user for the size of the array and then create an array of type Student - in a different method;

```
 public static Student[] createArray()
```

I'm unsure as to how to execute this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are nearly there - how do you initialise (create) an array of objects of a class? Then just return this initialised array from your method

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
public static Student[] createArray()
    {
     int inputLength = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Number of students"));
     Student students[] = new Student[inputLength];

    return students;

    }
```

Comment: I have; // Method that asks user for size of array.
    public static Student[] createArray() {
 
    Scanner userInputEntry = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputLength = System.out.println("Enter size of array:");
    Student students[] = new Student[inputLength];

    return students; 

    }             but it won't work

Comment: Hope I can still help you, change 
`userInputEntry = new Scanner(System.in); int inputLength = System.out.println("Enter size of array:");`
to
`userInputEntry = new Scanner(System.in); System.out.println("Enter size of array:");
int inputLength = userInputEntry.nextInt()`
you can't get an input from `System.out.println`